# What's a good two-way encryption library implemented in Python?

Tags: python, encryption

The authentication system for an application we're using right now uses a two-way hash that's basically little more than a glorified caesar cypher.  Without going into too much detail about what's going on with it, I'd like to replace it with a more secure encryption algorithm (and it needs to be done server-side).  Unfortunately, it needs to be two-way and the algorithms in hashlib are all one-way.

What are some good encryption libraries that will include algorithms for this kind of thing?

Comment: "the algorithms in hashlib are all one-way" -- that's a matter of definition.  Hashes are defined as one-way.  Ideally, ONLY one-way, although some can be reversed.  Perhaps you should rephrase your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it's two-way, it's not really a "hash".  It's encryption (and from the sounds of things this is really more of a 'salt' or 'cypher', *not* real encryption.)  A hash is one-way *by definition*.  So rather than something like MD5 or SHA1 you need to look for something more like PGP.

Secondly, can you explain the reasoning behind the 2-way requirement?  That's not generally considered good practice for authentication systems any more.

Comment: It's because a vendor-provided application has strange requirements for external authentication.  But you've convinced me that we need to work with that vendor to find a better way.

Answer (score 21):

I assume you want an encryption algorithm, not a hash.  The [PyCrypto](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto) library offers a pretty wide range of options.  It's in the middle of moving over to a [new maintainer](http://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/), so the docs are a little disorganized, but [this](http://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/doc/#crypto-cipher-encryption-algorithms) is roughly where you want to start looking.  I usually use AES for stuff like this.

Comment: I got voted down?  I'm pretty sure this is exactly what he is looking for.

Comment: +1: I can't see any reason you would be voted down for this either.

Comment: +1: not an assumption, a matter of definition.  A two-way hash is broken.

Answer (score 6):

[PyCrypto](http://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/) supports AES, DES, IDEA, RSA, ElGamal, etc.

I've found the documentation [here](http://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/doc/).