# Storing passwords with python

Tags: python, passwords, storage

I have a program I'm writing in python, and I have the need to store some passwords. These passwords will be the passwords to ftp servers, so it's important that they're not just plainly visible to everybody. This also means that I can't store a non-reversible hash of the password like you would on a webserver, because I'm not checking if somebody inputs the right password, I'm just relaying the password to somebody else.
So what's the best way to store passwords? I'm using python, and the program will be linux-only.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/721436/whats-a-good-two-way-encryption-library-implemented-in-python .

Answer (score 6):

You could use the system's key ring, e.g. GNOME key ring or KDE wallet.

There's a Python module called [keyring](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/keyring) that supports multiple key ring providers. I have only tried it on Windows, where it doesn't yet work correctly. Seems like development isn't very active, but you should give it a try. You can also try the package "python-gnomekeyring" which is specific to GNOME and more low-level.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I'm looking for to secure my python scripts :)

Comment: I gave `keyring` a quick spin and it seems to work perfectly. Could you revisit your answer, either to more firmly support `keyring` (or a better module if you've found one), or to more specifically detail what you've found doesn't work with it?

Comment: I have tested `keyring` on both OS X and Windows and it seems to work flawlessly on each platform. I also checked the implementation (since it's pure Python, that's easy enough) and I can't see anything concerning about it.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the distribution you can probably store it in the keychain if one is available.

Otherwise take a look at some of the encryption algorithms available (PGP/GPG, DES, AES etc) and their Python ports/modules but this is hard stuff which you *have* to get right.

Comment: Yes use a OS provided service rather than write your own.

Comment: If you use PGP or AES or whatever, don't you have to store a password in the python script to decode the passwords, then someone could just open the python source file and read the key to decode the password?

Comment: Not if you make that password a user input. A single password to remember them all :-) Or alternatively you could use keyfiles without passphrases. I don't know how high level his security needs to be.

Comment: if the password is userinput ... then you would need to store the plaintext in the file so that the user could then encrypt it with their custom key

Answer (score 2):

There's the convenient and insecure way: just store them as plaintext and if you are truly using FTP (and not, for example SFTP) then they will be as secure as the machine they are hosted upon (which means not really very secure). FTP was written in a time when sending a plaintext password over the wire was considered "safe enough"; those days are gone. Even encoding the plaintext passwords in the python source doesn't really help you as at some point you have to un-encode them.

Secure methods require a little more setup. Here is a [decent tutorial](http://support.suso.com/supki/SSH_Tutorial_for_Linux), I expect there are better ones.

Answer (score 0):

Check out netrc on Linux (use man or [this](http://linux.die.net/man/5/netrc)) and then look at [this Python module](http://docs.python.org/library/netrc.html)

If the netrc has the appropriate information you can use ftp at the command line without entering user and password - they are looked up in the file.  Some things to note: the file has be restricted to user read/write only (0600) or it may be rejected by ftp.  If that works, then you are ready to use it from Python.

A much better idea would be to avoid ftp altogether (where the password is sent in plain-text) and use sftp. Copy your public key from the machine running the Python script to each target machine and let ssh automatically login for you in a secure fashion.

Answer (score -4):

I would recommend hashing the password a hash is a one way function so can't be worked back to find a plain text version of the password (unlike an encryption).

[MD5](http://docs.python.org/library/md5.html) is a algorithm that I like and is already implemented in Python. You could always add a salt to the hash like `abdPasswordABDA` where Password is the password. Then store the hash in a file or database and just hash it again before it gets checked. SHA1 is another hashing algorithm that you could use.

Comment: He can't use hashes, because he's supplying the passwords, not checking them.

Comment: Besides using a hashed pw for authentication does not help since these still gives access to your db.

Comment: I haven't voted, but this answer acquired -4 probably because the two hashing algorithms mentioned are a poor choice for password hashing. They are too fast.